# how to print from a symbolic relationship?

Tags: linux, unix

i'm using linux and i created a symbolic link in my directory from another file. now, i want to print the records shown in that file in alphabetical order. i tried to do lp and lpr [symbolic file name] within the directory it is located, but kept getting a error with something along the following:

The program 'lpr' can be found in the following packages:

any ideas for how to do this? i feel like this is basic, but i cant find anywhere how to do this even though i have been searching.

thanks for any insight.

Comment: Your system doesn't have the `lpr` command. Being a symbolic links is not an issue, at all. If your print command can print regular files, it will print symlinks to regular files just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use yum or whatever software update/install program your system has - to install lpr.
You may already have cups, which does the same things lpr does.   As @janos already mentioned links are not the problem, your system software does not match your expectations about what is there.

This question really belongs on superuser.com